# How to add custom widget area to WooCommerce product category pages, just above the footer

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to add a custom widget above the footer on all pages (except landing page). All has worked well except for the Woo Commerce category pages.

I registered the widget area in my child theme functions.php

```
function register_custom_widget_area() {
register_sidebar(
array(
'id' => 'footer-box-area',
'name' => esc_html__( 'Footer box widget area', 'theme-domain' ),
'This puts a widget area at the bottom of the page' => esc_html__( 'Widget area for new footer boxes', 'theme-domain' ),
'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title-holder"><h3 class="widget-title">',
'after_title' => '</h3></div>'
)
);
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_custom_widget_area' );
```

And added the code below to the other page  templates where I want the widget to appear

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-box-area' ) ) : ?>
<div id="secondary-sidebar" class="footer-box-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-box-area' ); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Whenever I try to add the same code to the archive-product.php I get a unexpected syntax error.

My theme is Astra.

Any ideas of what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this. I removed the < and > before and after the statement. So, the following code worked:

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-box-area' ) ) : ?>
<div id="secondary-sidebar" class="footer-box-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-box-area' ); ?>
</div>
<?php endif;
```